# mouse middle click not working after using trackball

Tags: mouse

I had logitech marble mouse on my laptop, and I used this tutorial, successfully, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logitech_Marblemouse_USB
to make my trackball work properly (middle click, scroll, back button...)

Now I am back to normal mouse which has just two extra buttons for back and forward, but it is not working properly. So now the mouse works, with the left and right click and scroll, but nothing else. The biggest problem is that now middle click is not working, which is extremely useful for copy/paste, and also two extra buttons that I have are not working (for back and forward).

Can anybody help me with this problem? I tried a few things, searched Google, but nothing helps... It is probably something about settings for trackball, but I don't know how to put everything back to state before installing trackball.

I am using ubuntu 12.04...

Answer (score 1):

OK, just to report that I fixed problem after reading some tutorials and a lot of experimenting, and I hope somebody will find this useful.

Problem was that, after installing trackball, somehow mapping for buttons for any mouse was changed (or I just made some mistake while installing trackball). So, I only had to do remapping.
First I found device with

```
xinput list
```

then run

```
xinput get-button-map <device id>
```

and remember numbers (output) of this command.
Then I used

```
xev
```

to check which number is assigned to which function
and then I replaced those numbers with my required button mapping, using:

```
xinput set-button-map <device id> 1 9 3 4 5 6 7 2 8
```

You might need to play around and see what configuration works best for you.